# p-norm inequality for two random variables

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, lp-spaces, integral-inequality, distribution-tails

I read the following result in a book, however I believe that there is a mistake in the proof. Do you know of any book that proves this result, or do you have an idea on how to prove it?

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two nonnegative random variables defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ such that $X \in L^p$ for some $p \in (1,\infty)$. If it holds that for every $\alpha >0$, $$\alpha \mathbb{P}(Y \geq \alpha) \leq \int_{\{Y \geq \alpha\}} X d \mathbb{P},$$
then $$|| Y ||_p \leq q ||X||_p,$$ where $p^{-1}+q^{-1} =1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's first assume that $Y \in L^p$. Using the identity

$$\mathbb{E}(Z) = \int_{(0,\infty)} \mathbb{P}(Z \geq r) \, dr \tag{1}$$

which holds for any non-negative random variable $Z$, we find that

\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(Y^p) &= \int_{(0,\infty)} \mathbb{P}(Y^p \geq r) ~ dr \\ &= p \int_{(0,\infty)} r^{p-1} \mathbb{P}(Y \geq r) \, dr. \end{align*}

It follows form the given inequality and Tonelli's theorem that

\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(Y^p) &\leq p \int_{(0,\infty)} r^{p-2} \int_{\{Y \geq r\}} X \, d\mathbb{P} \, dr \\ &=p  \int_{\Omega} \int_{(0,\infty)} r^{p-2} 1_{[0,Y]}(r) \cdot X \, dr \, d\mathbb{P} \\ &= p \int_{\Omega} \int_0^Y r^{p-2} X \, dr \, d\mathbb{P} \\ &= \frac{p}{p-1} \int_{\Omega} Y^{p-1} X \, d\mathbb{P}. \end{align*}

Hence, by Hölder's inequality,

$$\mathbb{E}(Y^p) \leq \frac{p}{p-1} \|X\|_p (\mathbb{E}(Y^p))^{1-1/p}.$$

Rearranging this inequality, we conclude that $\|Y\|_p \leq q \|X\|_p$ with $q=p/(p-1)$.

In the general case, i.e. $Y \notin L^p$, we can apply the above reasoning to $\min\{Y,n\}$. Note that the inequality

$$r \mathbb{P}(Y \geq r) \leq \int_{\{Y \geq r\}} X \, d\mathbb{P}$$

remains valid if we replace $Y$ by $\min\{Y,n\}$.

**Remark:** The result is often used to prove Doob's maximal inequality for martingales. The idea of proof is taken from *Measures, integrals and martingales* by R. Schilling (he doesn't state the result independently, though).